# Why AWS SDK causing Jest Open Handle error?

Tags: amazon-web-services, jestjs, aws-sdk, amazon-cognito

I'm using jest for my backend testing. Here I'm login to aws using aws-sdk. I get the response successfully, then complete the test case, but then jest throws an error about open handles.

[image]

```js
const login = (options) => {
    const cognito = new aws_sdk.CognitoIdentityServiceProvider();
    const request = cognito.initiateAuth({
        "AuthParameters": {
            "USERNAME": options.username,
            "PASSWORD": options.password,
        },
        "ClientId": options.CLIENT_ID
    });

    return request;
};
```

After searching, I found people have this error when connecting with database, and not closing database connect / their nodejs server. These issue is not with my application as I'm my backend is completely serverless.I is not an express app.

Comment: Have you figured this out?

Comment: This issue was resolved same day i think. I cant remember exactly what caused it but it was something related to the incorrect response mapping from my side. I was not closing mapping the response from sdk properly

Comment: @ShadabFaiz can you elaborate more on "not closing mapping the response from the sdk".

Comment: @qasimalbaqali Its been too long since this issue was raised. I dont remember this at all, but by looking at my previous comment, I give the response must be returning some token, I would need to pass that token to the function that closes the connect. But i'm not 100%. It would be better if you can check the response.